# Aurelia converted values and dataTables

Tags: date, datatable, aurelia

I'm using DataTables jQuery plugin in Aurelia component. using column ordering and it works well excluding columns with dates. 
Inside this columns I'm using value-convertet to convert `isoString` value to `DD.MM.YYYY` date format. Value covreters usage leads to wrong date column ordering, but if I'm not using value-converter everything works well. Unfortunately I didn't find any reason why it doesn't work correctly.

Wrong filtering example: I see rows with date value like `27.05.2010` before `18.05.2017`

DataTables init:

```
$('#searchResultsTable').dataTable({
    destroy: true,
    searching: false,
    paging: false,
    orderMulti: false,
    order: [[ 2, "desc" ]],
    dateFormat: 'DD.MM.YYYY'
});
```

Date value converter (using *moment* library):

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

export class DateFormatValueConverter {
    toView(value: Date, format: string): string {
        if (value) {
            return moment(value).format(format);
        }

        return null;
    }

    fromView(value: string, format: string): Date {
        var isValid = moment(value, format, true).isValid();
        if (value && isValid) {
            return moment(value, format).toDate();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
Ordered with value converter 
[image]

Orderd without ValueConverter(ordered like it should 2017 year value on the top)[image]

Comment: When you say the ordering is _wrong_ when you're using ValueConverters - is it actually in the same physical order as when you don't use them?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean when telling **"physical order"**. According to example I gave of wrong ordering it will be - 18.05.2017 before  27.05.2010 (but in isoString format) if I don't use Value Converter

Comment: You say the order is wrong when you use a value converter, but is it actually just the same order as when you don't use one?

Comment: added images to question with examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ordering mechanism of the data table is working correctly - it's your understanding that's off I'm afraid.

When ordering in descending order, any that start with `27.` will be at the top, as they're the "*biggest*". Within all the dates that start with `27`, it'll order on the month, biggest first, and then the year.

The order mechanism doesn't realise you're ordering a date so we need to look at the Custom Sorting Plugins;

https://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/

And specifically the Date-De plugin - as that matches your date format;

https://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/date-de

An example taken from the above page;

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    columnDefs: [
        { type: 'de_datetime', targets: 0 },
        { type: 'de_date', targets: 1 }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Just found solution by myself. https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/datetime-moment   added this plugin. But your solution should work too. So I accept you answer. Thank you!